# Parsing a HTML text area's contents on the server

Tags: html, parsing, textarea

I have a textarea on a page which I use for receiving keywords from a user so that frequencies in text documents can be calculated.

At the moment however, if a user specifies keywords on different lines, e.g:

```
dale
farm
evictions
```

Only the server, carriage returns and line breaks are preserved. So for the three keywords above, my servlet receives:

```
dale
farm
evictions
```

What is the best way to get rid of the carriage returns and line breaks? Is it best to scan and replace them by a space which is the delimiter the page requests of the user?

Thanks

Mr Morgan.

```
        String s1 = "mr morgan\r\nis a fool"; 
        String s2 = s1.replaceAll("[\n\r]", " "); 
        System.out.println(s2);
```

Seems to give me what I want. Thanks to the respondents.

Comment: What do you mean by "on the server"?

Comment: My question doesn't have 'on the server' in it.

Comment: @MrMorgan In the title: `Parsing a HTML text area's contents on the server`

Comment: The title of your question does though.  How is the textarea retrieved?  It should get all of the lines from which you can parse.

Comment: Oops: I mean that the textarea contents are received by a sservlet simply as typical request.getParameter("textareaContents");

Comment: I've revised the question following a program change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What have you tried so far?

You have to [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/function.explode.php) the text by newlines (`\n`):

```
$keywords = $_POST['keywords'];
$keywords = explode("\n", $keywords);
// $keywords is now an array
```

If the keywords are separated by a comma:

```
$keywords = $_POST['keywords'];
$keywords = explode(',', $keywords);
// $keywords is now an array
```

And for `<meta name="keywords" />` you have to replace all newline characters by a comma

```
$keywords = $_POST['keywords'];
$keywords = str_replace("\n", ', ', $keywords);
```

Working example: http://codepad.org/r0tZtXwb

Comment: So far the contents of the textarea are simply received as a string on the server using a servlet. They are then parsed but I find certain words missing.

Comment: I've revised the question following a program change. My boss is very picky about showing code so unfortunately I can't.